# It is possible to run all instances of a subprocess successively?

Tags: camunda

It is possible to run all instances of a subprocess successively?

My process constis many service tasks and some are not allowed to run parallel. Can I run them into a own Thread Pool/Job Executer, where is only 1 Thread/Job allowed to run? Or have anyone a smarter idea?
[image]

Comment: I dont get the question. You want to execute service tasks one by one?

Comment: Hi. As example I start 100 instances from process with the job executer, but I will execute the subprocess one by one. In actuality, the subprocess is not always tiggered.

Comment: You can model this with a sequential multi instance

Comment: Like this? https://camunda.org/share/#/process/520da92b-258e-4969-b31f-321c84f87392, I do not think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup an extra process engine (additional to default), deploy the process only there and set its jobexecutor to use a threadpool of size=1.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the subprocess in one by one you can also model it in the main process and use an embedded sub process (see example 1) or you use a call activity (see example 2) and call the sub process.

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Comment: But when I run 10 processes in parallel, the subprocess is executed in parallel. But I want the subprocess is executed sequentially over all running instances.  I need a "synchronized" for the subprocess.

Comment: Ah ok now i get the point. You can set jobs to exclusive but this is only useful on jobs on the same process instance, since you create different process instances I think this is not possible. Maybe you can change your model to create one process instance and use multi instance to spawn parallel executions and then use a sub process with asynBefore and exclusive flag so the job which will execute the sub process are executed exclusively.

Comment: Ok. The problem is, I running over 100k procces instances. If I start all into one process instance and use multi instance, so kill this the JVM. Thank you for your support.